# iPhone: UITableView search bar header - how to make it stay in place?

Tags: iphone

How do I make the search bar stay on top of the UITableView? It goes out of view when I scroll.. I'm using a UITableViewController which makes things trickier..

Comment: you add search bar on view and then add a table view.

Comment: Hmm I thought so.. thought I could get away with using a UITableViewController. Ah well, thank you my friend.